# filtering or checking datagridview

Tags: vb.net

I need help when filtering or checking if either one or more datagridview cell is null or not before saving the data. I have tried several codes but there is always an error. Below is the picture:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what you are trying to do.  Maybe you want some kind of auto-complete process to run.  Is that it?  See the code sample below.

```
Imports System
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Drawing
Imports System.Linq
Imports System.Text
Imports System.Windows.Forms
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Namespace WindowsFormsApplication4

    Public Class Form1
        Inherits Form

        Public Sub New()
            MyBase.New
            InitializeComponent
            Me.initializeFields
            Me.loadCustomerFromNorthwindDbToDgv1
        End Sub

        Private CustomerId As DataGridViewTextBoxColumn

        Private CompanyName As DataGridViewTextBoxColumn

        Private Address As DataGridViewTextBoxColumn

        Private Sub initializeFields()
            Me.CustomerId = New DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
            Me.CustomerId.Name = "CustomerID"
            Me.CustomerId.DataPropertyName = "CustomerID"
            Me.dataGridView1.Columns.Add(Me.CustomerId)
            Me.CompanyName = New DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
            Me.CompanyName.Name = "CompanyName"
            Me.CompanyName.DataPropertyName = "CompanyName"
            Me.dataGridView1.Columns.Add(Me.CompanyName)
            Me.Address = New DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
            Me.Address.Name = "Address"
            Me.Address.DataPropertyName = "Address"
            Me.dataGridView1.Columns.Add(Me.Address)
        End Sub

        Private dv As DataView

        Private Sub loadCustomerFromNorthwindDbToDgv1()
            Dim conConnect As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection("Data Source = EXCEL-PC; Database = 'Northwind.MDF'; Integrated Security = true")
            Try 
                Dim dAdapter As SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT CustomerID, CompanyName, Address FROM Customers ", conConnect)
                Dim DS As DataSet = New DataSet
                Dim bs As BindingSource = New BindingSource
                dAdapter.Fill(DS, "dsCustomer")
                Me.dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = false
                Dim dt As DataTable = DS.Tables("dsCustomer")
                bs.DataSource = DS.Tables("dsCustomer")
                Me.dv = New DataView(DS.Tables("dsCustomer"))
                Me.dataGridView1.DataSource = bs
            Catch ex As Exception
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString)
            End Try

        End Sub

        'will do the search for CompanyName name everytime you type in @ the textbox search
        Private Sub textBox1_TextChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
            Me.dv.RowFilter = ("CompanyName like '%' + '"  _
                        + (textBox1.Text + "' + '%' "))
            Me.dataGridView1.DataSource = Me.dv
        End Sub

        Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
            ' TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'northwindDataSet.Customers' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
            Me.customersTableAdapter.Fill(Me.northwindDataSet.Customers)
        End Sub
    End Class
End Namespace
```